# Upgrade to webSocket message in play web sockets using scala

Tags: scala, sockets, playframework

I am new to play framework and implementing web sockets using iteratees in Scala but when I run in browser it prints **upgrade to Web sockets required** with no compiler error. I have attached my snippet here. Please help. Am using Ubuntu platform.

Comment: where is you snippet?

Comment: Since am not allowed to embed images here (due to not enough reputation points ) here's the link to them.                                               [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xtZ7F.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6xGaF.jpg

Comment: sorry for inconvenience if you had

Comment: You need to open a websocket connection using javascript and through that you need to communicate.

e.g:
`wsConn  = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/routetoyouraction");` 

and then send and receive messages using this wsConn. for more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: @AniketPandey, there are other, much more convenient options to post a code snippet other than screenshots of your IDE :) Just paste the code and indent every line with at least 4 spaces to make it a code block, more info about Markdown syntax [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @curios i have created clients that connect to it. Everything is fine. It is just when when am not using index function like `def index = Action {   Ok("hello world") }' it is coming up with the above message  **Upgrade to WebSocket required**. Otherwise it displays the message of index function (only if i use it).